# Add stopwords to a standard azure search analyzer?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I'm using the en.microsoft analyzer in my Azure Search index. For the most part it is working well, but I need to add a handful of domain-specific stopwords. Is there any way to add stopwords to the existing analyzer? Or to implement a custom analyzer that inherits it's behavior from a standard one, and just override the stopwords while leaving everything else as is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can't inherit from an existing analyzer, you can create a pair of [custom analyzers](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/custom-analyzers-in-azure-search#property-reference) (one for indexing and one for search) that is functionally equivalent to `en.microsoft`, but with your own stopword list. Here is how it would look in the index definition payload of the REST API:

```js
{
  ...
  "analyzers": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
      "name": "my_search_analyzer",
      "tokenizer": "my_english_search_tokenizer",
      "tokenFilters": [ "my_asciifolding_search", "lowercase", "my_stopword_filter" ]
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
      "name": "my_index_analyzer",
      "tokenizer": "my_english_index_tokenizer",
      "tokenFilters": [ "my_asciifolding_index", "lowercase", "my_stopword_filter" ]
    }
  ],
  "tokenizers": [
    {
      "name": "my_english_search_tokenizer",
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.MicrosoftLanguageStemmingTokenizer",
      "isSearchTokenizer": true,
      "language": "english"
    },
    {
      "name": "my_english_index_tokenizer",
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.MicrosoftLanguageStemmingTokenizer",
      "isSearchTokenizer": false,
      "language": "english"
    }
  ],
  "tokenFilters": [
    {
      "name": "my_asciifolding_search",
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.AsciiFoldingTokenFilter",
      "preserveOriginal": false
    },
    {
      "name": "my_asciifolding_index",
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.AsciiFoldingTokenFilter",
      "preserveOriginal": true
    },
    {
      "name": "my_stopword_filter",
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.StopwordsTokenFilter",
      "stopwords": [ "put", "your", "custom", "stopwords", "here" ]
    }
  ]
}
```